# Using A case in a select to detect a null date

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to return all records that have a Fee against them that need paying (pd.[Plan Fee] not null), But do not have a date of invoice being raised against them (pd.[Raise Plan Fee] NULL).

I'm relatively new to using cases, so not sure this is the correct way to execute what i'm trying to return, any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
    SELECT * FROM
vw_ProjectsDetailed AS pd WHERE
   CASE  pd.[Plan Fee] WHEN NOT NULL THEN pd.[Raise Plan Fee] NULL
```

Comment: `case` is an *expression*, not a statement, are you just after `where pd.[Plan Fee] is not null and pd.[Raise Plan Fee] is null`?

Comment: Is `... where pd.[Plan Fee] is not NULL and pd.[Raise Plan Fee] is NULL;` what you want? Using `case` in a `where` clause tends to render the query non-[sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).